# Show dialog when screen if off

Tags: android

I work on a recording app.

I have a situation when `the internal storage runs below 10 MB` and then I stop the recording and `show a dialog` to the user.

The problem is when the user has, let's say, 100 MB free, starts the recording, lock the phone, and records in the background.

After a while the storage runs below 10 MB, the recording is stopped, but no dialog shown to the user, `BECAUSE SCREEN IS OFF`.

How can I show a dialog to the user after he unlock the phone and enter the app? I will show a notification too, but my app targets android 2.3+ and no notifications for 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wake up the screen using a `PowerManager` given the apps context:

```
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "TAG");
        wakeLock.acquire();
```

To unlock it you use the `KeyguardManager`:

```
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
        KeyguardLock keyguardLock =  keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
        keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

In your manifest, put:

```
     < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
     < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

See [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and [Keyguard Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html) in the Android Developer Resources.

**EDIT 1:**

There are some `WindowManager.LayoutParam` flags that are all related that you could try, but they only work in full-screen environments and the last one might be your best bet:

- [FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)
- [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
- [FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD)
- [FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON)

Comment: There is no other method of doing this? I don't want to show the dialog IN THAT MOMENT. I have notification for that. The problem is the recording is stopped automatically because < 10 MB, the user enter the app thinking is still recording and THEN he must see the dialog saying:"Hey, your phone is out of mem. Recording was stopped". Now no dialog is shown when he enters the app.

Comment: So what do you want? You need to 1) unlock the phone 2) Wake the screen and then I need clarification: 3) display a dialog when the app is opened? Why is the dialog not showing when he opens the app then?
... The other thing you could try is some flags, but they only work in full-screen activities. I'll edit my answer